# Eigenvalues related to oblique projections

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples, projection-matrices

Let $P = P^2$ be a real (non-zero) projection matrix and define the matrix $M$ as
$$
M = P + P^\top - P^\top P.
$$
What choices of $P$ renders $M$ positive semidefinite?

If $P$ is symmetric (orthogonal projection), then $M = P$, which is positive semidefinite since each eigenvalue of $P$ is either $0$ or $1$. Are there examples of non-symmetric $P$ (oblique projection) for which $M \geq 0$?

In the $2 \times 2$ case I believe that symmetry is necessary. The most general form of non-symmetric projection matrix that I'm aware of is
$$
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
\frac{a(1-a)}{b} & 1-a
\end{pmatrix},
$$
with $b \neq 0$. In this case, the eigenvalues of $M$ are given by
$$
\lambda_1 = 1, \qquad \lambda_2 = -\frac{(a(a-1) + b^2)^2}{b^2}.
$$
$M$ is consequently positive semi-definite only if $b = \pm \sqrt{a(1-a)}$, which ends up making $P$ symmetric after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M\ge0$ only if $P$ is an orthogonal projection. Suppose $M\ge0$. Then for every $x\in\ker(P)$, we have
$$
\|M^{1/2}x\|^2=x^\top Mx=x^\top(Px)+(x^\top P^\top)x-(x^\top P^\top)(Px)=0.
$$
Therefore $M^{1/2}x=0$. In turn,
$$
0=Mx=(P+P^\top-P^\top P)x=P^\top x.
$$
Thus $\ker(P)\subseteq\ker(P^\top)$. By interchanging the roles of $P$ and $P^\top$ in the previous argument, the reverse inclusion is also true. Hence $\ker(P)=\ker(P^\top)$. But then $\operatorname{ran}(P)=\ker(P^\top)^\perp=\ker(P)^\perp$, so that $P$ is an orthogonal projection.